# How to obtain coefficient values from Spark-MLlib Linear Regression model (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I'd like to obtain coefficient values of Linear Regression(LR) model in Spark-MLlib. Here I use the 'LinearRegressionWithSGD' to build the model and you can find the sample from the following link:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-linear-methods.html#regression

I could get the coefficient values from Spark-ML Linear Regression. Please find the reference link from below.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took first lines of model creation from the first link you sent:

```
val model: LinearRegressionModel = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations, stepSize)
.run(training)
// Here are the coefficient and intercept
val weights: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = model.weights
val intercept = model.intercept
val weightsData: Array[Double] = weights.asInstanceOf[DenseVector].values
```

The last 3 lines are the coefficient and intercept

The type of `weights` is 
`: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`

That is a wrapper around the Breeze `DenseVector`

Comment: Is there any way to find the column/field name of the coefficient ? Here the 'weights' return the coefficients as Array and I'm not sure which column's coefficient it is ? Can you please help me this ?

Comment: Simply, I'd like to know what are all the fields I've considered for building a Linear Regression model. Is there any API available ?

Comment: I have not looked at this for a while.
I think that I just set a simple test project up in Scala and looked at the objects possibly from Eclipse.